# What Problems Might Occur if I Overlap Multi-Register Modbus Data Items?

Tags: modbus

It is common to use 2 registers to read/write a floating point value in Modbus.
My question is what problems or compatibility issues arise if I specify my device register map with overlapping data as follows..

`40001 (float a), 40002 (float b), 40003 (float c), 40004 (float d)`, and so on.

Float (a) can be read at 40001 with FC03, number of registers is 2.
Float (b) can be read at 40002 with FC03, number of registers is 2.
Float (a) and (b) can be read at 40001 with FC03, number of registers is 4.

Comment: In a Modbus Master, it seems that the addresses for every Slave PV, be it float or double, must be individually programmed. Is this true, and if so, does the Master's programming environment allow the overlapped address space (because it is not validated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will render your device to become not a `modbus-compatible` device, but just a `modbus-like` device.

The drawback is that there are plenty of modbus clients, mostly SCADA systems, which would simply stop working with such register map. So if you don't care about 3rd party clients, you can do it, but what is the purpose?

### UPD

Also you get undefined behavior on reading registers which belong to different values at the same time. What is the expected output of reading single word at `4002`? LSB of `a` or MSB of `b`?

How do I read 2 consequent numbers (`a` and `b`)??

> Modbus is already only modbus-like when it comes to multi-register
>   values

Wrong, it is still modbus, but whenever you ready multi-register values or implement time stamps, you explicitly define them in documentation and you rules should not violate general modbus rules like mention above. There is nothing wrong in telling you are using 2 registers with MSB BOM.

So the answer is **it could work for some specific cases but is generally not usable at all**.

Comment: The purpose is because the client device is highly configurable, to the point that it is unknown whether PV 1 - 99 are floats, doubles, or integers. So the overlapped address scheme allows using addresses 1 - 99 regardless of typing. I thought it might be acceptable because Modbus is already only modbus-like when it comes to multi-register values. The scheme is very simple for someone that has to calculate addresses for any PV.

I have never worked on the Industrial / User side of a Modbus device, and so I ask if the scheme is generically usable.

Comment: Is it necessary, or automatic in some way, that the LSB of (a) would be read stand-alone? I agree that this would not be supported using my addressing scheme. Reading a single word at 4002 would read MSB of (b). In practice, would you not read the whole of (a and b), separately at 4001 and 4002 respectively, or together at 4001?

Comment: In practice there are systems (like well known `Citect` SCADA) which automatically group registers when reading them. You just tell the addresses and SCADA joins them together in one modbus frame (if they are near and do not violate max length of course). So what will happen if you try reading `a` and `b` in one request?

Comment: If (a) and (b) are automatically joined in one request, the request will work just fine, unless the SCADA does not request enough registers (4). The problem could be that the SCADA will complain or be unable to join the request because the address of (b) overlaps (a). If the request is manually joined, with only specifying the starting register and the number of registers, the request will work fine.